# body.addEventListener called after checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i'm confused about the behaviour from an addEventListener response.

[In this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uqUp/) you can see a Label for a checkbox called "My Profile" and a Popup, which is shown if the checkbox is checked, through the magic of CSS.
I'm trying to make it disappear if the popup is shown and the user clicks outside of the popup div...

But the reason i can't get it to work is, if you click on the label with the id 'header-profile-popup-toggler' first the Body.addEventListener, then bbb2.addEventListener(the checkbox) and afterwards once more the Body.addEventListener is called.

But if you click outside the Label Body.addEventListener is called only once, same as i click on bbb.addEventListener(the div).

**Does someone** know why the body.addEventListener is called after the bbb2.addEventListener??

---

For explanation.

Absolutely, i would only call

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   if(bbb2.checked==true&&e.target!=bbb){
       bbb2.checked=false;
   }
});
```

Only if the Popup is shown (bbb2.checked==true) and you clicked outside the div (e.target!=bbb) uncheck the checkbox.

But since the body.addEventListener is called once more after bbb2.addEventListener and both statements are true - the checkbox is checked and the checkbox is outside of the popup div - the checkbox is unchecked instantaneous.

Thanks for any Support!

---

**I got it!**

Because of the constallation of a label for the checkbox the addEventListener is called for every Element, in this case for the Label and Checkbox with one click.

So, first of all the Label Event is called, then the Body. After that, the Checkbox Event and once more the Body Event are triggered.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer to your question and mark it as the right solution. This will let this question no longer be displayed as unresolved and will make it easier for people with similiar issues to find the solution quickly.

Comment: If you solved the porblem mark your answer as accepted!

Comment: you can't accept your own answer for 24 hours. i will do it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

Because of the constallation of a label for the checkbox the addEventListener is called for every Element, in this case for the Label and Checkbox with one click.

So, first of all the Label Event is called, then the Body. After that, the Checkbox Event and once more the Body Event are triggered.

With the following Script i made a fully functional Popup-Menu, which also works if Javascript is deactivated:

```
var isOutSide = true,
bbb=document.getElementById('header-profile-popup'),
bbb2=document.getElementById('header-profile-popup-toggler'),
bbb3=document.getElementById('header-profile-popup-toggler-label');
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
   if(isOutSide){
       document.getElementById("header-profile-popup-toggler").checked = false;
   }
   isOutSide = true;
});

bbb.addEventListener('click', function(){
   isOutSide = false;
});
bbb2.addEventListener('click', function(){
   isOutSide = false;
});
bbb3.addEventListener('click', function(){
   isOutSide = false;
});
```

On [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxr4L/) you can test it in Action